# Are web browsers havens for exposing login credentials?

Tags: security, authentication, browser, credentials, login-control

I happened upon a post on the net recently (sorry, can't remember where exactly) that advised not to save passwords in your browser because they can be harvested somehow.

Is this true?

From a prudent security & protection point of view, should we not allow the browser to save login credentials?

Hope this is not the case...otherwise, the security exposure is deeply concerning and not being able to store credentials is a huge & major pain in the butt.

Thanks for clarifying how secure browsers actually are.

Comment: Someone in the same household/library/netcafe could learn your password by opening the website and changing the password field to readable. True, the attacker could also just log in and change the password, but most services require the old password when changing it to a new one and in some cases it might be more interesting to not let the owner of the account know you can log in.

Comment: OK @Chavez, thanks. But you stated "household/library/netcafe". I'm okay with members of my household that use my computer on a family-share basis, but what do you mean by "netcafe" for example. If I take my laptop to a wifi hotspot, are you saying that someone in the same vicinity can gain access to my browser's repository of my login credentials?

Comment: Not with the method I mentioned. In that case it would be easier to redirect the user to a phishing page or using malware to retrieve the keychain. In general, security is as strong as its weakest link, and the weakest link is pretty much always the user. Because of this, functions to improve usability will always tend to compromise security.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are suggesting or discussing. We might not be on the same page here @Chavez. I am not referring to web sites and any server-side storage of passwords. Nor am I referring to cookies, etc. <more>

Comment: I am referring to the browser, say Google Chrome, whereby when you login to a web site that requires credentials and then you respond with credentials Chrome offers a pop-up window asking you if you wish to save the username and password in your browsers privacy settings area. So if you do that, are you exposed in your browser whereby someone can look into your machine's browser and harvest the credentials? </end>

Comment: Other than injecting a phishing page, not that I know of. The problem I have with this approach however is that this barely scratches the full scope of information security. Hence my remark, your level of protection will only be as strong as the weakest link. So no, I would not recommend storing credentials in a browser.

Comment: Thanks @Chavez. I upvoted your comment.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/94015/8340) a couple of days ago. Basically if there's any XSS flaw on the site in question and the browser populates the username and password fields then an attacker could grab the credentials.

Comment: *Basically if there's any XSS flaw on the site in question and the browser populates the username and password fields then an attacker could grab the credentials.* -- So are you saying @SilverlightFox that if a website I have logged into at one point in my life and elected to have my browser store the login username and password and if that site has some XSS flaw, anyone out there in the world could harvest my username and password that I have saved in my browser back on my machine even if my computer is powered off?

Comment: No. You'd have to be actively using your computer at the time and would have to visit the attacker's site where the XSS attack is launched from. This could be a site an attacker has enticed you to visit (come have a look at this cat), or a site you visit that has been compromised.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [hotly debated](http://blog.elliottkember.com/chromes-insane-password-security-strategy) topic almost 2 years ago. Google Chrome at that time just showed the passwords without asking for any credentials.

Even though the [Chrome security lead](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6166886) is correct that if someone has physical access to your machine, all bets are off. The general consensus was that it was way too easy for someone to harvest passwords if you stepped away from your desk for a moment.

Chrome changed the saved password dialog and now asks you for credentials before showing any saved passwords.

I save most of my passwords in the browser, except for the most crucial ones.